# apache2 DirectoryIndex change does not bypass cached index

Tags: apache, caching, polymer, apache2

I am trying to make sure that visitors to my website see the latest version. To this end I have written a script to rename appropriate files and requests so that they append a fresh version number at build time. This includes the index file, let's call it `index-v123.html`.

I have uploaded this built source and pointed my `apache2` server to the new index file by including

```
DirectoryIndex index-v123.html
```

in my `apache2.conf`. I have restarted it, and when viewing the website in chrome incognito mode or on hard refresh I can see that all the new files are loaded and the website works as expected.

My issue is that in my normal browser, when I visit the URL, I still load up a cached version of `index.html`. Clearly changing the `DirectoryIndex` didn't convince the client to go to the new index file like I'd hoped...

So can I do anything to make this happen?

(Also may be relevant: I am running a progressive web app using Polymer 2.0, with a `service-worker.js` that is built automatically by `polymer build`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a service worker issue: `service-worker.js` was being cached on the client side, and hence was providing outdated content as if the client was in offline mode. Could only be updated by deregistering the worker. The solution was to implement `max-age=0` on the service worker at the apache2 server side:

```
<Files index.html|service-worker.js>
    FileETag None
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</Files>
```

Was surprised this wasn't better highlighted in the polymer build/production docs somewhere. For reference, in the [google primer](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates) on service workers it says:

> The caching headers on the service worker script are respected (up to
>   24 hours) when fetching updates. We're going to make this opt-in
>   behaviour, as it catches people out. You probably want a max-age of 0
>   on your service worker script.